# метод __init__ и аргумент self в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что происходит во время вызова `__init__` под капотом python? Каким образом реализован этот метод, а также `self`?

Comment: Ничего особенного, `__init__` — это просто метод, который автоматически вызывается для свежесозданного экземпляра

Comment: Тут надо написать про  метод `__new__`,  а инит это просто колбэк по его завершению

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829497/c-equivalent-of-pythons-init  не то ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__init__` - метод, который вызывается при создании экземпляра класса, в нём можно объявить члены класса, а так же выполнять какие-либо другие действия (например, увеличивать счётчик созданных экземпляров)

`self` - первый аргумент любого метода по соглашению. При вызове метода `self` присваивается ссылка на экземпляр, для которого был вызван метод. То есть, для метода класса всегда передаётся хотя бы один аргумент - сам экземпляр ( если не брать в расчёт статические методы). Пример:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def show_a(self):
        print(self.a)

    def show_b(self):
        print(self.b)
```

Объявим класс, создадим экземпляр и проведём пару манипуляций

```
test_ex = Test()
test_ex.show_a()
Test.show_b(test_ex)
```

В первом случае аргумент `self` задаётся неявно, а во втором явно. Но отличий в исполнении нет

Comment: Вопрос не про то, как использовать. А про то, как реализована имплементация